# Hello, working on Practice It-Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, concatenation

***So here is the initial Question***

"The following program attempts to print a full name given a first name and last name as parameters. The last name should be printed in full, starting with a capital letter and followed by all lowercase letters. A comma and the capitalized first name initial should then follow. For example, the call printName("Abby", "Stepp") should output "Stepp, A." to the console. The initial code contains several kinds of errors. Fix the code below so that it compiles and runs properly."

***Here's the answer you start off with***

```
// Prints a full name where last is followed by a ", " and the capital letter
// of first, which is followed by a "."
    function printName(first, last) {
        string fullname = last + ", " + substring(first(0, 1)) + ".";
        return fullname;
    }
```

***Here's my answer***

```
// Prints a full name where last is followed by a ", " and the capital letter
// of first, which is followed by a "."

function printName(first, last) {
    var fullName = last + "," + first + ".";
    return fullName;
};
```

I want to understand why my code is not passing, in my answer I am passing in a concatenated value into `var fullName` I have a previous question through the same platform that did not have to concatenate in which that was passed and is similar to my answer here so I am thinking that it has something to do with the value that is being passed into `var fullName`

Here's a sample of that problem, I would like to know the difference between the two problems. Both these questions are asking me to fix these Errors

***Question***

```
public static int add(x, y) {
    int sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}
```

***Answer***

```
function add(x, y) {
    var sum = x + y;
    return sum;
};
```

Comment: Hello, work on fixing this title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the first letter of the first name, and make sure that it is capital; first.toUpperCase().split()[0] outputs the first letter and ensures that it is capital.

```
function printName(first, last) {
    var fullName = last + "," + first.toUpperCase().split()[0] + ".";
    // "," should be ", " ; with a space
    return fullName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input!!

Comment: Hi, I input the function into the program, and it still says that it does not pass

Answer (score 0):

For the first code snippet:

this expression: `substring(first(0, 1))` gets the first letter of `first`. In your code you just concatenate last and first, whereas the original answer concatenates last and the first letter of first. For example:

The first answer would give you:
`Smith, J.`

Your answer would give you:
`Smith, John.`

I'm not entirely sure what the second part of your question is asking, if you clarify in a comment I will update my answer.

Comment: I wanted to know what the difference between the first problem, and the second problem was because both questions are functions with two parameters, and inside the functions is a variable that holds a concatenated value, in which we return that function which gives us an answer. Why problem 2 passed, but problem one did not basically, thank you. I think I have an answer from up above, but if you have a different way of explaining it, or have a different way to solve problem one Id love to see your answer :)